# Problem with \small command

Tags: formatting

Why has the effect of the `\small` command been extended to item (e)?
[image]

```
\item $a_n = \dfrac{a^2_{n-1}}{a_{n-2}}, \textrm{ for } n \geq 2, a_0 = 1 \textrm{ e } 
                                           a_1 = 2$ (\small{{\textbf{\textit{Hint:}} SDSADSADASsscsc $\log a_n, n = 0,1, 2,...$ }})


\item $a_n = a^3_{n-1}a^2_{n-2}, \textrm{ for } n \geq 2 \textrm{ e } a_0 = a_1 = 2 $
```

Comment: `\small` is a switch, not a command. So it stays active until the next switch or inside of a group.

Comment: To only apply small to the part in (), use `({\small\textbf{\textit{Hint:}} SDSADSADASsscsc $\log a_n, n = 0,1, 2,...$ })` instead. For comparison: `\small{....}`, original, wrong; `{\small ...}`, changed, small is only active inside of the set of `{}`.

Comment: Scoping the font switch is covered in this FAQ: [How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25249/5764) (possible duplicate). In particular, you need `{\small ...}`, not `\small{...}`.